# Is there a better way to get subcontrol name?

Tags: qooxdoo

I am trying to get a reference in the "scrollbar-y" of the class qx.ui.list.List

Using the createChildControl event how can I check if the widget is the one named "scrollbar-y"?

So far I found two ways of which none seems elegant but both seem to get the job done

```
this.__list = new qx.ui.list.List()
this.__list.addListener("createChildControl", this.__onListCreateChildControl, this);
```

and later

```
__onListCreateChildControl: function (e){
        debugger;
        var child = e.getData();
        if (child.constructor === qx.ui.core.scroll.ScrollBar && child.getOrientation() === "vertical") {
            child.addListener("scroll", this.__onListScroll, this);
        }
    },
```

This checks implicitly. Apparently if it is a scrollbar and it is vertical it is our y scrollbar. Yeah it kinda looks like a duck but I have to check for both

`if (quacks like one && walks like one)`

The other way is

```
__onListCreateChildControl: function (e){
            debugger;
            var child = e.getData();
            if (child.$$subcontrol === 'scrollbar-y') {
                child.addListener("scroll", this.__onListScroll, this);
            }
        },
```

which uses the internal variable $$subcontrol. This works fine but it uses qooxdoo internals which seems like a hack.

P.S. I did try getChildControl('scrollbar-y') in various phases but since it is created in "as needed" basis I always get null.

Comment: But calling `getChildControl('scrollbar-y')` should enforce the creation of the child control instance if the second parameter is not true. It may be of course that the correstponding DOM  element creation is delayed until the widget queue runs. See tinyurl base URI+ /gusrrsf

Comment: My initial code was somethng like  tinyurl /hxszabn. It didn't work. Tried to get child control on Window appear. Tried on List appear. Every time I got null. Now I subclassed qx.ui.list.List for other reasons and did getChildControl('scrollbar-y') in the sublass constructor. Now it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right! There is no "straightforward" possibility to retrieve the ID (or name) of a widget created as a child of another widget in terms of child control creation.

Therefore I've submitted a PR to github which does exactly that: namely retrieving the id/name of a child control by exposing the internal `$$subcontrol` variable via a method `getSubcontrolId` https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/pull/9140

The PR is currently in review state.

Comment: FYI the PR has been commited to master: https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/commit/f74ba773de14e738bfe96539752be823c2c412ca